# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForDebug'

Tags: java, android, debugging, proguard

I must use certain librairy  in my project.
When I want bebu my application I receive an indication which says to me that my code exceeds 65k method.
Thus I decided to use Proguard.
But I receive this error.
my code of buile.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "transplusafrica.delydress"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    } 
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.2.0'
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.0'
 }
```

I receive this error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForDebug'.
```

> java.io.IOException: proguard.ParseException: Expecting type and name instead of just '***' before '(' in line 114 of file 'C:\Users\AMANI\AndroidStudioProjects\DelyDress\app\build\intermediates\proguard-rules\debug\aapt_rules.txt'
>   Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: proguard.ParseException: Expecting type and name instead of just '***' before '(' in line 114 of file 'C:\Users\AMANI\AndroidStudioProjects\DelyDress\app\build\intermediates\proguard-rules\debug\aapt_rules.txt'
>   :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForDebug FAILED

Comment: Which version of the Android gradle plugin are you using? This looks like a bug there as the rules generated by the aapt task seem to be wrong.

Comment: No thats the gradle version you are using. You will have something like this in your build.gradle: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:x.x.x'`

Comment: It is good this  classpath'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my case it was line in `aapt_rules.txt` with `-keepclassmembers` that include my layout file. And after check this layout i'm found empty `android:onClick=""` param. Removing this solve my problem.