# Error occurs after enabling proguard in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-proguard, android-studio-2.3

After enabling proguard in debug mode I am getting the following error :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForDebug'.
```

How to solve this?

Gradle dependencies :

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.scalified:fab:1.1.3'
    compile 'com.github.rjsvieira:floatingMenu:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Could you please share your Gradle file and Proguard file in question?

Comment: remove     minifyEnabled true from your gradle. that worked for me

Comment: @Liya that is not solution , if turn on Proguard then `error` ll be arrive

Comment: you can check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38436236/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclassesandresourceswithproguardfo/38560811?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @NikunjParadva I have added the gradle depencies in question. Can't add the whole file as stackoverflow showing this error (too much code)

Comment: @NikunjParadva and I haven't edited proguard file yet.

Comment: One of the third party libraries was the reason behind this error.

Comment: use latest version of their libs